# How to declare class name in Swift before I create one?

Tags: swift

This is what I need:

```
func mockNetworkClientWithResponse(response: [String: AnyObject], withRequestType type: DBRequestType = .GET) -> DBMockNetworkClient {

    class DBMockNetworkClient: DBNetworkClient {

    }
}
```

The return value is undefined yet, so there is an error about `use of undeclared type`. How to declare it before I create this?

Answer (score 3):

Move the declaration outside the function:

```
class DBMockNetworkClient: DBNetworkClient { ... }

func mockNetworkClientWithResponse(response: [String: AnyObject], withRequestType type: DBRequestType = .GET) -> DBMockNetworkClient {
    // ...
}
```

If your function must return a value of type `DBMockNetworkClient`, the class `DBMockNetworkClient` needs to be accessible at the scope at which the function is declared, and this can only be done by defining it at an equal or higher scope. Callers of the function must be able to know what the returned type is, otherwise the function is unusable.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe that this is impossible. Now vaguely strong typed language, even ones with a more advanced typesystem like Swift or Scala, can know, nor infer the Type of what you want to return when you define the type in the function.

Can't you solve this with an interface?

Like (in pseudocode):

```
function A( T p1, T2 p2) -> anInterface {

   class X implements anInterface {
   }
}
```

The definition of the interface of course must preceed the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `typealias` as a workaround, so

```
typealias DBMockNetworkClient = Any
```

with this the compiler will see the type that you want to return, but inside the function you have the class which will be returned.

However in this case you won't be able to use the properties of this class, since the declaration is only inside that function. You can only pass the result to somewhere else.